# Match a substring using regex pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a substring using regex.

An example of the substring I've got is:
`"{{simple-array.text}}{{simple-array.option}}"`.

Using the following pattern: `{(.*?)}`, I get the following two matches: `{{simple-array.text}` and `{{simple-array.option}`.

I'm not sure how to get the following output using regex:
`{simple-array.text}` and `{simple-array.option}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close!

**Regex Pattern**: `{({.*?})}`

**Returns**:
`{simple-array.text}` and `{simple-array.option}` within group 1

[Regex101 for validation](https://regex101.com/r/2CYNQY/2/)